# why always attribute android:hintTextColor not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I always show up but not found

attribute android:hintTextColor not found.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="249dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/password_msg"
        android:hintTextColor="#757575"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

please help me.thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`android:hintTextColor="#757575"` isn't a `TextView`/`EditText` attribute, but `android:textColorHint="#757575"` is, check out [DOC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#attr_android:textColorHint)

[`hintTextColor` is param of `TextInputLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout#attr_TextInputLayout_hintTextColor), you've probably mixed some naming :)

Comment: Thank you. I followed the yellow exclamation mark and pressed the triangle. It turned out to be an error.